# CORS error when trying to POST data from angular project to a Spring Web service project

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have a Angular front-end where I want to POST and GET data from my Spring web service. When I try to send POST data to the service I get the following error: [CORS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5cnQ.png)

The code I use to send the POST data from Angular is:

```
  this.http.post(environment.LOGIN_URL, value)
      .map((response: Response) => {
         console.log('TEST');
         //response.json();
      })
      .subscribe();
```

When using GET I use this.http.get(environment.LOGIN_URL) etc.. etc.. And that works like expected

In my spring service I use the following method code:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "{ \"key\": \"value\", \"foo\": \"bar\", \"aa\": \"bb\" }"; // return test Json data
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/message2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void index(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
    System.out.println(payload);
}
```

}

I have been stuck on this for a while now and answers I found on the internet don't seem to work with me. If I forgot some information let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to stand up the project and test it out, this is a bit difficult. However, do you have the WebMVCConfigurer setup?

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
           registry.addMapping("/auth/message").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

Also, I'm assuming your Controller has defined /auth as part of the URI?

Try adding the WebMvcConfigurer bean, and mapping to the correct endpoints.

What you've provided here looks like it should work, however there's no issues with setting controller level and method level @CrossOrigin configurations. I'd try them out both ways to attempt to narrow down the issue. Try adding @CrossOrigin at the class level as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this quick answer. I found out that it's not the Spring webservice that created this problem but the spring gateway service (My bad, should have said in the post that I use this too). Can I still use this solution or do I need to do something different for gateways?

Comment: CORS just sets a header on the local resource, your gateway is receiving the request and forwarding it. You'll need the gateway to also provide Allow-Access-Origin: * (I forget the exact header).